# I am not able to run my project on android studio. It is showing the following error whenever I try to download emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android SDK is up to date.

```
Running Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installer
Unable to run Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installer: Cannot start process, the working directory 'C:\Users\anusha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver' does not exist
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem, see [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for.html).

Quoting from there:

- Make sure your AMD CPU supports virtualization and BIOS has NOT disabled it. As BIOS options are different among vendors, please refer to your system manufacturer's manual.
- For Windows 10: All Windows features enabling Hyper-V (either explicitly or silently) must be turned off. See the screenshots below for a few examples.
- Open a Windows command console with administrator privileges.
- Go to `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver`.
- Run silent_install.bat. Make sure you see the desired output from the installer: STATE: 4 RUNNING